# how to redirect on opportunity page [in sf1 only] in salesforce one using javascript navigate methods

Tags: salesforce1-app

```
<apex:component controller="SF1_UserAgentIdentifyController">
  <h5><div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">{!message}</div></h5>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" onclick="javascript:sforce.one.navigateToURL('/006');">Back</button>
```

but its not taking me to the default opportunity page which appear in sf1 when we click on opportunity tab.

[image: Mobile UI]

And I am having a VF page when back button is located and want to come back on the above screen within the salesforce one.

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE vikasgupta. You might want to take a look at both the [Salesforce1 Mobile App Admin Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1appadmin.meta/salesforce1appadmin/) and [Salesforce1 Mobile App Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/) to see if the answer to your question can be found within.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" onclick="sforce.one.navigateToURL('/006');">Back</button>
```

Comment: @geekmartian i tried it but not working.

Comment: @vikasgupta works fine for me, the `javascript:` part in the onclick event was not necessary. Do you see any error on the Javascript console?

Comment: it shows an error saying that "your page is not optimized for mobile or enable the page for mobile app....."

Comment: Go to Setup/Develop/Pages, select the page where the button is located and check "Available for Salesforce mobile apps"

Comment: I have edited my question please look in to it.